# startup scripts for amazon linux ami

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, startup, init.d

I'm trying to start a script every time I start my amazon micro instance (amazon linux ami).
I tried to put it in /etc/init.d/ and linkted it to /etc/rc.d/ but the script is not executed.
I've also looked at user-data scripts, but as I understand the documentation they are only executed on the first startup of the instance. 
What do I have to do to run my script on every startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Init.d/rc.d are primarly used for services. Any scripts that you install here have to be enabled to run at boot `chkconfig service on`.

Since it sounds like you are really just running a one time script. You can set it up to run with cron using the `@reboot` flag instead of providing a time.